# CSS Positioning bug for text on image

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-position

I have an image which has `position:absolute`, so I can place a `position:relative`text on it.

That all works great so far. The only problem is,  that the **text is shown in the upper browser corner while  the image is still beeing loaded**. On the lokal enviroment  I could not see this, but in the live enviroment it becomes obvioud.

Static width/height statements are not an option, since the whole page is responsive.  How to work around this? Is there  another way to tell the text 'roughly' where it is supposed to stay when 'later that day' the img is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong with what you described in the question. A absolute element should be inside a relative positioned parent. This allows the absolute positioned element to position itself according to the parent. Better way is to have a relative parent whose elements are the image and text.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/qwLp9f9y/6/

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://de.fwsx.co/mbergs/images/home-header.jpg" />
    <span>Sample Text</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}

div img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

div span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    text-align: center;
}
```

Another option is to set the image as a `background-image` of the parent and then position the text. In this way you'll have to worry about the text position.

**Here is the demo for background-image:** https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/qwLp9f9y/8/

Comment: Sorry, I was messing up things. Please seee edited. My problem is, that while the image is still beeing loaded the with/height values are not (yet) existing for the browser. I need a workarount only for the loading of the image. The actual positioing is working alright.

Comment: @BernhardPrange Trust me, some other issue is waiting for you when this is fixed. Because this approach is not good for what you are trying. The reason why it works  on local environment is that the image is present locally and doesn't need time to load. While when you deploy it, the time is taken to load the image. That's the time when things are messed up.

Comment: @K K I had this figured out so far. So what is the right approach then? As I told you - I do not have measurements before, since it is all responsive.

Comment: @BernhardPrange Try replacing the text part with the way which uses background-image trick. Here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/qwLp9f9y/8/  Check the second div which uses background-image

Comment: @BernhardPrange For responsive, check this: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/qwLp9f9y/9/ . Try resizing the result panel to see the effect